# Supress SQL Warnings on a per File Basis in Database Project

Tags: sql, visual-studio, database-project

I have two SQL Server Database projects in a Visual Studio Solution.  One of them is a legacy database which I am just using a database reference in my main database project.  I have a view in my main database project similar to

```
SELECT *
FROM [$(ReferenceDb)].[dbo].[Table1] t
WHERE t.IndexedColumnId IN (1, 55, 99)
```

I am getting

> SR0004: Microsoft.Rules.Data : A column without an index that is used
>   as an IN predicate test expression might degrade performance.

The reference database has an index on this column.  Please note this is simplified code for demonstration purposes.  I'm actually joining on tables in the reference DB to tables in my main DB.  If I move this simple code to the reference DB project I don't get any warnings.  It appears like the main database project isn't picking up on the indexes in the reference database.

What I'd like to do is to suppress this warning; but I don't want to do it for the entire main database project.  I only want to suppress it for certain SQL views/stored procedures, etc.

I'm looking for something similar to the in source suppression of warnings available in C# files like.

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "args")]
```

but I need to be able to do this in the .sql files in the main database project.

I debated turning off the warnings for the entire project but really don't want to go that route.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Project Properties. You apparently have Code Analysis turned on.  You'll still turn it off for the whole project, but you can turn off that particular warning.

I don't think it's possible to turn off this particular warning for just one file as it's a project-level analysis.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid.  I know how to turn it off for project but I want it left on but just ignoring it in specific spots.  similar to the in file suppression that they have with C# by using the "#pragma warning disable xxxx" feature or the "System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage" metadata tags.

Looks like this question may not have a valid answer until potentially a later version.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible to turn it off per file. You can suppress warnings, but not the rule checks. I know it's not what you were looking for, but not aware of any way to accomplish what you want right now.

Comment: +1 for trying...but leaving as unaccepted.  Maybe in a couple years with release of new version their will be a solution.  I basically came to same conclusion.  Only work around I thought of was to have these "special" cross-database views in their own project that I turn warnings off.  Then add that as an additional reference back into my main db project.  Seems to be overkill at the moment with deadline approaching ;(  I'll have to live with the technical debt introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Suppressing SQL Server Static Code Analysis warnings in SSDT on a per-file basis is supported in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019.

1. Create a new XML file in your SSDT project root named `StaticCodeAnalysis.SuppressMessages.xml`.

   - Ensure that it's also added to the `.sqlproj` file with a Build Action of `None` and not copied to the output directory.
2. Copy and paste this template into that file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <StaticCodeAnalysis version="2" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.StaticCodeAnalysis">
       <SuppressedFile FilePath="dbo\Stored Procedures\Procedure1.sql">
           <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0007" />
           <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0004" />
           <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0005" />
           <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0015" />
       </SuppressedFile>
       <SuppressedFile FilePath="dbo\Functions\Function1.sql">
           <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0007" />
       </SuppressedFile>
   </StaticCodeAnalysis>
   ```
3. Rebuild your database project and those rules will now be suppressed in those files.

**Warning**: Ever since I updated to Visual Studio 2019 16.7 I've been having issues with SSDT where Visual Studio will often completely freeze and lock-up when I right-click an SSDT warning in the Error List window - or if that works then it will definitely freeze when I choose the suppression options in the context menu, so I have to manually add suppressions to this file by-hand, ugh.

Answer (score 0):

in theory in the `<Build>` node of the project you can have e.g. `<SuppressTSqlWarnings>71562</SuppressTSqlWarnings>` but I haven't found this to work

Comment: Using VS 2019 Community Edition Version 16.9.5, your suggestion works as described